# SQL-Query for maximum AND minimum

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the right (MySql)- query in order to get the highest AND the smallest value of a table?I got this, but that's faulty:

```
SELECT * FROM temperaturs ASC LIMT 3  UNION SELECT * from temperaturs  ORDER BY `Temperatur_Celsius` DESC LIMIT 3;
```

This is faulty,too:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelle_name ORDER BY spalte1 DESC LIMIT k UNION SELECT * FROM tabelle_name ORDER BY spalte1 ASC LIMIT k
```

Comment: The first SELECT has no ORDER BY. And do UNION ALL. And correct LIMIT spelling.

Comment: Why is it faulty?

Comment: you can easily use min() and max() function of SQL query why you need all column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query just needs parentheses:

```
(SELECT * FROM temperaturs ORDER BY `Temperatur_Celsius` ASC LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * from temperaturs ORDER BY `Temperatur_Celsius` DESC LIMIT 3);
```

Note:  I switched from `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  This will allow multiple rows if the table has fewer than 6 rows.  In general, `UNION` is a bad practice because it incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.

MySQL needs parentheses when subqueries to a `UNION`/`UNION ALL` use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT`.

Comment: No ORDER BY in first SELECT. LIMIT spelled as LIMT.

Comment: Works great.Thank U!